# Facebook iOS SDK - UIWebView dialog for login - how can user manually cancel?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having a problem here. I've modified a portion of the source code to prevent my app from launching the Facebook app or Safari for authentication. Instead, a UIWebView will be displayed as an overlay on my app.

However, in the dialog. I noticed there isn't any CANCEL button. Which makes me wonder what happens if the user decides not to login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had forgotten to copy the FBDialog.bundle over to my project! ahh!

Comment: I have the same problem but FBDialog.bundle is ok...what else could be wrong ?

Comment: Thanks, should've found your answer last week =.= been wasting days trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using FB graph API for facebook login.? If yes,
Then the view that you see for login is programmatically created.
Look into the FBGraph.m for its implementation.
There you can add a cancel button and add your cancel logic there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did noticed there were codes which was supposed to add a close button. But nothing was appearing. Apparently, I had forgotten to copy the FBDialog.bundle over to my project! ahh!